# Finding a non constant solution to $ (x')^2+x^2=9 $

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How do I find a non-constant solution this equation? I've tried to solve for $x$, but the final answer should be in the form of $x(t)=...$

$ (x')^2+x^2=9 $

I'm not sure where to start.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Brute force:**
$$\begin{align}(x'(t))^2+(x(t))^2= 9&\implies x'(t)=\pm \sqrt{9-(x(t))^2}\\
&\implies \dfrac{x'(t)}{\sqrt{9-(x(t))^2}}=\pm 1\\
&\implies \dfrac{1}{3}\dfrac{x'(t)}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{x(t)}{3}\right)^2}}=\pm 1 \end{align}$$

Now use $\arcsin'(s)=\frac{1}{\large \sqrt{1-s^2}}$.

Comment: Do you mean integrate both sides using that identity?

Comment: @Bob That is what I mean.

Comment: Still not sure what's going on. I've integrated both sides and got arcsin(x(t)/3) = x(t).

Comment: Your RHS is wrong. Can you fix it and follow up?

Comment: arcsin(x(t)/3) = t?

Comment: @Bob Yes, sort of. Should be $\pm t + C$, for a certain constant $C$. Can you finish?.

Comment: I'm not sure where to go from here. It appears as though I need to solve for x(t), but how? And once I do that I don't even think that will be the final answer still.

Comment: @Bob Do you know how $\arcsin$ relates to $\sin$?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the equivalent relationship would be sin(t+c) = x(t)/3

Comment: Which means x(t) = (1/3)sin(t+c)?

Comment: @Bob Close, but not quite: $$\begin{align} \arcsin \left( \dfrac{x(t)}{3}\right)=\pm t + C&\implies \dfrac{x(t)}{3}=\sin(\pm t+C)\\
&\implies x(t)=3\sin(\pm t+C)\end{align}$$
Therefore your solutions are $x(t)=3\sin(t+C)$ and $x(t)=3\sin(-t+C)$ defined for real $t$.

Answer (score 15):

How about this:  notice that $(x')^2 + x^2 = 9$ is a circle in $x$-$x'$ space, a circle of radius $3$.
Then the point $(\frac{x}{3}, \frac{x'}{3})$ lies on the unit circle.  That means there will be some  function of $t$, $\theta(t)$, such that $x(t) = 3\cos \theta (t)$ and $x'(t) = 3\sin \theta (t)$.   Based on this information, and assuming $\theta(t)$ is differentiable (which can be proved via the implicit function theorem), we have $x'(t) = -3\theta'(t) \sin \theta (t)$ as well from which we infer $\theta'(t) = -1$, leading to $\theta(t) = c - t$ for some constant $c$.  So $x(t) = 3\cos(c - t)$.

Hope this helps.  Cheers!

Comment: Purdy.${{{{}}}}$

Comment: @Git Gud:  Thank you, thank you!

Comment: @nbubis:  glad you enjoyed it.  I exploited similar technique in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/473458/why-do-all-solutions-to-this-equation-have-the-same-form, but in a much more sophisticated way.  Shameless self-promotion! ;)

Answer (score 7):

Hint: try differentiating your equation with respect to $t$ - and use $x'\neq 0$

---

You have $(x')^2+x^2=9$

Differentiate with respect to $t$ to obtain $$2x'x''+2xx'=0$$

Divide through by $2x'$ to get $$x''+x=0$$

This is a second order linear differential equation, which should have a familiar solution. You then have to put the general solution back into the original equation to find a solution which works for that.

Comment: There is no t variable to integrate, which is what is throwing me off.

Comment: @bob - differentiate, don't integrate!

Comment: Note that $x'=0$ is also a possible solution, telling us there aren't any more solutions than sines, cosines, and constant functions.

Comment: @nayrb The question asks for a non-constant solution, my explanation uses the hint, which includes $x'\neq 0$

Comment: Yup, just commenting that sines and cosines are the only non-constant solutions.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $$2x'(x''+x)=0.$$
$ $  $ $

Comment: What do I do from here? How did you figure that out?

Comment: The general solution of $x''(t)+x(t)=0$ is $C_1\cos t + C_2 \sin t$.